# Enable num-lock at boot Raspberry Pi

Tags: boot, raspbian

I am trying to toggle num-lock on my Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian jessie, I need it to run during the initial CLI boot up (before <hostname> login: or startx), I have tried numlockx and setleds but none work until logged in.
I already have a script that runs during boot and was hoping to incorporate it into the existing script.
In case you were wondering it is so I can have num-lock for my password.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=numlock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup. There's a way.

1. Open up `/etc/kbd/config` with your favorite editor.
2. Search for a line that says `LEDS=+num`. It should be on line 67 if I'm not mistaken.
3. Uncomment it. I assume you know how to uncomment since I think you know scripting.
4. Profit.

Comment: thanks I will try it now and get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: It worked a charm! Now I just have to get used to not pressing numlock

Comment: @TrentFitzpatrick I also have to get used to it, since I got used to pressing numlock on my laptop every boot.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OYOi1JB now if only I had a faster way to code.....

Comment: @TrentFitzpatrick Try not doing it on the pi. Maybe mount a folder on the pi as a network drive on Windows, then do the actual coding on Windows (using sublime or notepad++).

Comment: @TrentFitzpatrick Or maybe get a comfy chair and place the keyboard on your lap.

Comment: I have my comfy chair but I need the pi because I'm live testing

Comment: http://imgur.com/W3kEJgr

Comment: My boot script is here I am making it for my school's Pi:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tQc5Mf9i

Comment: @TrentFitzpatrick Interesting script.

Comment: @PandaLion98 does it work on Rpi B+ with Jessie? I've just tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @VMMF Tested it with all of my Pis (Pi Zero - Pi 3). Works.

Comment: I don't have any file at `/etc/kbd/config`. I tried `sudo touch /etc/kbd/config`, but it complained that there was "No such file or directory".

Comment: @Eptin Are you using Raspbian?

Comment: @pandalion98, yes, the latest version of Raspbian Stretch with desktop

Comment: @Eptin Let me check.

Answer (score 7):

While this isn't directly answering the Raspbian Jessie question, for those other Googler's who run Raspbian Stretch, which doesn't have `/etc/kbd/config`, here's the solution:

- Install numlockx: `sudo apt-get install numlockx`
- Edit this file: `sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf`
- At the end of that file, add this line: `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on`
- Save the file and reboot, and you NumLock key should still be on

Sources:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=192383

which in turn cites:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375920/numlock-on-startup-on-linux-mint-18-2

Comment: Good to know there is a solution for X. But sadly that does not help in Raspbian Light. :(

Comment: Note also this will not work, as per the question, "before <hostname> login: or startx".  It will also not work at all unless you are using lightdm (the GUI login).

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/kbd/config` has been removed in Raspbian Stretch, but you can set the numlock state using `/usr/bin/setleds` instead.

For example, to enable numlock in all VTs:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Turn Numlock on for the TTYs:
for tty in /dev/tty[1-6]; do
    /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < "$tty";
done
```

You put this script in `/usr/local/bin/numlock`, and invoke it at boot time, for example using a systemd service (`/etc/systemd/system/numlock.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=numlock

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/numlock
StandardInput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service with `systemctl enable numlock.service`.

Source: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=134006#p650222

Comment: Note that this will only work for CLI. It does not work on Stretch on the UI boot.

Answer (score 1):

On Raspbian 10 (Buster), there's a slightly easier way. In a terminal:

```sh
sudo apt install numlockx
```

In the default text editor, `vim.tiny`, or `nano` save the following text into the file `~/.config/autostart/NumLock.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Numlock on
Comment=Set numlock to on at logon
NoDisplay=true
Exec=numlockx on
NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;XFCE;
```

That's it. This is based on how the system already configures keyboard and mouse settings.

Answer (score -4):

Command line:

```
sed -i 's/#LEDS=+num/LEDS=+num/' '/etc/kbd/config'
```

Comment: How exactly does this work? How would the OP get this to run before setting the hostname and before startx?

Comment: You just run it once, it modifies the file forever. It is the programmatic equivalent to the manual steps up there.

Comment: Most sysadmins like to know how the programs/scripts in their systems work. Serious ones audit everything that needs to run in a mission-critical environment. People also like to make sure that random scripts/commands they get online are not malicious. This is why we want to know what this does, not for us, but for the laypeople.