# How to setup hama keypad 00053224 on RASPBIAN JESSIE

Tags: raspbian, driver, keyboard, raspbian-jessie

I bought a [Hama 00053224 Keypad](https://www.hama.com/00053224/hama-keypad) and I want to use it with my raspberry pi to easily enter digits. Is there a way to install or configure a driver for it on raspbian jessie?

Because nothing happens if I just plug it in. If I try it on my mac book, it works fine without configuration.

`lsusb` output (I have a Canon printer connected too):

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04a9:1772 Canon, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05a4:8003 Ortek Technology, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Its `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05a4:8003 Ortek Technology, Inc.`

I also tried capturing input with [python-evdev](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I can see the keypad:

```
>>> from evdev import InputDevice, list_devices
>>> devices = [InputDevice(fn) for fn in list_devices()]
>>> for dev in devices:
...  print(dev.fn, dev.name, dev.phys)
...
('/dev/input/event1', 'Keypad USB Keypad     ', 'usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input1')
('/dev/input/event0', 'Keypad USB Keypad     ', 'usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0')
```

But nothing happens if I try to capture the input.

**EDIT**

I'm pretty sure it has to do with numlock. Because I can see the same stuff as Peter here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123527/targus-usb-number-pad-not-working-in-debian-wheezy But I don't know how to change numlock setting. I tried uncommenting `LEDS=+num` in `/etc/kbd/config` but it does not work either.

**EDIT II**

I also tried with `setleds` (I'm pts over ssh):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ who
pi       tty1         Jan 31 10:40
pi       pts/0        Jan 31 10:42 (192.168.88.214)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo setleds -D +num < /dev/tty1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo setleds -D -num < /dev/tty1
```

But it does not work either :(

**EDIT III**

Tried with another keyboard with numblock on it. Uncommenting `LEDS=+num` in `/etc/kbd/config` works. It just doesn't have any effect on my usb keypad. But it's necessary to get the numbock working after boot.

`dmesg` output is btw:

```
[    4.319902] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.319928] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB Keypad
[    4.319937] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Keypad
[    4.326725] input: Keypad USB Keypad      as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:05A4:8003.0004/input/input2
[    4.373508] hid-generic 0003:05A4:8003.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Keypad USB Keypad     ] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
[    4.381664] input: Keypad USB Keypad      as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/0003:05A4:8003.0005/input/input3
[    4.433868] hid-generic 0003:05A4:8003.0005: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Keypad USB Keypad     ] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input1
```

Comment: It is a USB number pad; it may work simply by plugging it into your Pi. These usually present as an HID or keyboard to the system and don't require a driver.

Comment: Hi Steve, I thought that too, but it does not work :(

Comment: Have you tried it in another computer? What does lsusb show after plugging it in also, can you edit your question and add the output of dmesg?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just did. I also tried different usb ports

Comment: to rule out the oobvious have you toggled num locks?

Comment: uh, how can i toggle the num locks, I have only connected this keypad to the raspberry and on it is no num lock.

Comment: yeah, this is an odd keypad that does not seem to have numlocks

Comment: This looks like a start http://www.anites.com/2013/12/usb-keyboard-on-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: oh ok thx! I'll give this a try

Comment: @SteveRobillard I think it has to do with http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38794/enable-num-lock-at-boot-raspberry-pi but it did not help :(

Comment: If it is trying to be a keypad then capturing the raw output may not give you what you expect - perhaps it sends out keyscan codes that indicate a key being pressed or released and NOT the ASCII character that you expect (which is produced by the kernel keyboard handler that processes the key released codes via a mapping system to take account different keyboard layouts),  people with barcode or RFID scanners that emulate keyboards (I have both) also can have issues in getting the output from such devices where they want that to go - I still need to look around further in that area myself...!