# Enable num lock at startx

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have found "[Enable num-lock at boot Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38794/enable-num-lock-at-boot-raspberry-pi)", however this switches num lock on, then off again as I log into the GUI (with startx). How can I get num lock to enable each time I boot into the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using numlockx and added the `numlockx on` start command in a start up script.

I followed [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=10081) from the raspberry pi forum.