# no /etc/kbd in stretch lite?

Tags: keyboard, raspbian-stretch

I'm setting up a RPi 3 with stretch lite on top of which I've further installed the Raspberry Pi Desktop following [this guide](https://jp.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=133691). All is working fine, but as I went on to  [enable the numerical keypad of my keyboard at boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39035/63024), I noticed that I don't have the folder /kbd in /etc. I am positive that I didn't delete that folder (I had no reason whatsoever to do so). So, does stretch lite ship with this folder? Should I copy it from jessie so that I can tweak it to enable the numerical keypad? It seems anyway that /etc/kbd isn't required!